# Matrix norm in Banach space

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

How can I calculate the following matrix norm in a Banach Space:

$$
        A=\begin{pmatrix}
        5 & -2 \\
        1 & -1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
?$$

I have tried $$\|A\|=\sup\limits_{\|x\|=1}\|Az\|$$

and then did $$Az=\begin{pmatrix}
        5 & -2 \\
        1 & -1 \\
        \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 5x-2y \\ x-y \end{pmatrix}.$$

Now, how can I maximize the function $\|Az\|$? I'm not sure.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the definition of $||x||$? The answer will depend on it.

Comment: If you want to get an idea of what might be involved, solve it in the case $||x||$ is the square root of the sum of the squares of the components of $x$. This case you can solve using Cauchy's inequality.

Comment: If $\|\cdot\|$ is the Euclidean norm, then $\|A\|$ is just the largest singular value of $A$.

Comment: The norm is not specified in the problem. Should I just go with the square root of the sum of the squares of the compoments of $Az$, i.e. maximize $\sqrt{(5x-2y)^2+(x-y)^2}$ given the constraint $x^2+y^2=1$?

Comment: Or should I maximize $\{{(5x-2y)^p+(x-y)^p}\}^{1/p}$ given the constraint $x^2+y^2=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different norms for a matrix considered as an operator on a Banach space. If you want the operator norm of $A$ as an operator on 2-dimensional Euclidean space then the easiest way to calculate it is by using the C*-identity $\|A\|^2 = \|A^*A\|$, where $A^*$ is the Hermitian adjoint of $A$. In this case, $A^*A = \begin{bmatrix}5&1 \\-2&-1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}5&-2 \\1&-1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}26&-11 \\-11&5 \end{bmatrix}.$ Since $A^*A$ is a positive matrix, its norm will be its largest eigenvalue, which you can find in the usual way by solving the quadratic equation $\det(A^*A - \lambda I) = 0.$ Then take the square root to get $\|A\|.$

[This answer was posted on [MathHelpBoards](http://mathhelpboards.com/calculus-10/matrix-norm-banach-space-10270.html?posted=1#post47638).]

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the norm you choose to endow the vector space with, for instance if we consider $(\mathbb{R}^2,\|\cdot\|_\infty)$ where $\|(x_1,x_2)^T\|_\infty=\max_{i=1,2}|x_i|$, then

$\|A\|_\infty=\max_{1\le i\le 2}\sum_{j=1}^2|a_{ij}|$ so in your case we get $\|A\|_\infty=7$.

Answer (score 0):

My attempt

If the norm in the vector space is $2$ then each $(x,y)$ with norm equal to $1$ is represented as $(\cos{\theta},\sin{\theta})$:

$$Az=\begin{pmatrix}
        5 & -2 \\
        1 & -1 \\
        \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} \cos{\theta} \\ \sin{\theta} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 5\cos{\theta}-2\sin{\theta} \\ \cos{\theta}-\sin{\theta} \end{pmatrix}.$$

Then the norm (squared) is:

$$(5\cos{\theta}-2\sin{\theta})^2+(\cos{\theta}-\sin{\theta})^2$$
$$25\cos^2{\theta}+4\sin^2{\theta}-20\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}+\cos^2{\theta}+\sin^2{\theta}-2\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}$$
$$21\cos^2{\theta}+5-22\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}$$
$$21\cos^2{\theta}+5-11\sin{2\theta}$$
Derive:
$$21\cdot2\cdot\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta}-22\cos{2\theta}=0$$
$$21\cdot\sin{2\theta}-22\cos{2\theta}=0$$
$$\tan{2\theta}=\frac{21}{22}$$

Comment: This is exactly what I got. I have decided to proceed with Lagrange multipliers though, instead of converting to polar coordinates.